# Tkinter - How can I put a label on a Canvas in order to hide it?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

if I try to put a label on a canvas, the latter always stay on the top (see the image attached) but what abut if I want to put the canvas under the label?

[image]

below my example code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def ChangeinItalian():
    MyLabel.configure(text="Ciao Ciao Ciao Ciao:")
def ChangeinEnglish():
    MyLabel.configure(text="Hi Hi Hi Hi:")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("550x350")

MyFrame=Frame(root, background="#ffffff", highlightbackground="#848a98", highlightthickness=1)
MyFrame.place(x=5, y=5, width=535, height=300)

MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=16)
MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=10)
MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(4, minsize=10)
MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(6, minsize=16)
MyFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=16, pad=16)
MyFrame.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=16, pad=16)

ttk.Label(MyFrame, text="Introduction", background="#ffffff").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")



# I change the grid method options to cover the label with the canvas.. but it just an example.. what I want to do is put the label on the Canvas and not vice versa.
Canvas(MyFrame, height=1, background="#a0a0a0", highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="white").grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky="we")



MyLabel=ttk.Label(MyFrame, text="Hi Hi Hi Hi", background="#ffffff")
MyLabel.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")

ttk.Entry(MyFrame, width=70).grid(row=3, column=3)
ttk.Button(MyFrame, text="...", width=5).grid(row=3, column=5, sticky="we")

ItalianButton=ttk.Button(MyFrame, text="Italiano", command=ChangeinItalian)
ItalianButton.place(x=16, y=150)
EnglishButton=ttk.Button(MyFrame, text="English", command=ChangeinEnglish)
EnglishButton.place(x=16, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: I just added my code example, but it's not necessary.. I just want to put my label on the canvas and not vice versa. how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets have what's called a stacking order, which is initially defined by the order in which widgets are created. Widgets created later have a stacking order higher than widgets that are created earlier. When two or more widgets occupy the same space, tkinter uses the stacking order to determine which widget is on top.

In your case you're creating the label and then the canvas, meaning that the canvas has a higher stacking order and thus appears on top of the label.

If you want the canvas under the label, you can either create the canvas before the label, or use the `lift` or `lower` method to adjust the stacking order.

Comment: great! I didn't know about the stacking order. now I solved thank you, but.. I have another little question. what about if I want to add a blank padding (just 5 pixels) on the right side of my label "Introduction"? how can I reach this goal?

Comment: @TurboC: just read the documentation for the `grid` method.

Comment: no, you didn't understand. I meant to add a blank padding from a label point of view and not from a grid point of view. I'm speaking about the extend the lenght of the label just on the right.

Comment: @turboc, you can find the answers to questions like this by reading available documentation, and just a little experimentation.